# How to use panhandler and animated at the same time - react native

Tags: react-native

I am creating a tennis game on iPhone using react native. First part of motion is about moving the ball to the users. I did this by using animated class. But second part is about change the direction of ball in the direction of a swipe. Is there a way I could change the direction of an object in the middle of animation using panhandler?

Thanks!

Comment: Currently also struggling with this. My problem is ofc that my Animated.View animates based on an interpolated value (mapped to a left position in my render function), but now I want the same view to also animate based on a gesture's moveX value.